# Canot mount FreeNas 8 mirror in freenas 11

Tags: mount, nas, freebsd, software-raid, freenas

Have a freenas 8 with 2 disks on raid(Mirror) of 1Tb each and only 1Gb Ram. I didn't notice that it only have 1Gb ram and update to Freenas 10 because i need install OpenVPN. When the system boot up it was very slow and i thing that something goes wrong and do a fresh install on the usb stick of freenas 9. After i realize it have only 1Gb i upgrade to 8Gb and install a fresh instalation of freenas 11.

Now i can't import the raid to freenas. If i do LS on server i found a mirror/Nasmirror but on import and zfs status don't apear.

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Go back to freenas 8 backup your data. update to last freenas, restore the backup.

Comment: I'm looking into FreeNAS's stability and viability as a mature product based on problems people have. Is this typical of FreeNAS; lose everything and start over?